# JPA Meta-model is not getting generated through maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, jpa-2.0

I did as per

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

Hibernate 5.2.16.Final

Maven 3.3.9

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

When I do

```
mvn clean generate-sources
```

I am getting

```
[INFO] javac option: -proc:only
[INFO] javac option: -processor
[INFO] javac option: org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor
[INFO] javac option: -d
[INFO] javac option: C:\Users\myname\git\my-repo\my-repo-domain\target\classes
[INFO] javac option: -s
[INFO] javac option: C:\Users\myname\git\my-repo\my-repo-domain\target\generated-sources\apt
[INFO] diagnostic C:\Users\myname\git\my-repo\my-repo-domain\src\main\java\me\jigar\project\domain\package\domain\repository\MyDomainRepo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import me.jigar.project.domain.package.domain.MyEntityClass_;
                                                 ^
```

Comment: Does a mvn clean build work? This reads like a regular compilation failure